# How to convert PHP mysqli_result to serializable array

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to store mysqli_result object (enumerable) to Redis or memcached. It's ok to store results using mysqli_fetch_array (or assoc). But is it possible to store directly mysqli_result without fetching results? or is it possible to convert it into readable object?

Basic example what I need is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT ... query");

$redisObject->save("query_x", $result);

$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($redisObject->get("query_x"));
```

This example doesn't work because the result of mysqli_query is not serializable. What is the way to achieve it?

Comment: Not possible. A resource can't be serialized. Why don't serialize the data, like you said?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to serialize `mysqli_result` object. The way that this class is designed in PHP internals does not allow for serialization.

Usually, the application shouldn't handle `mysqli_result` object directly. This object should be abstracted from the application logic. If you want to serialize the data, you can simply fetch it all into an array using `mysqli_result::fetch_all()` method. This class doesn't really have anything else other than some convenience methods (which aren't really that convenient). It's just a way of exposing data from the MySQL operation to PHP. Fetch it into an array or a specialized data structure as soon as possible and discard the object.